# Dom4j - No such namespace prefix

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to create an .xml file but compiller says to me:

```
No such namespace prefix
```

I want to get:

```
<root>
    <header>
        <etd:name>test</etd:name>
    </header>
</root>
```

My code:

```
Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
Element root = document.addElement("root", getXmlNamespace()).addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:etd"), "some-url-there");
Element header = root.addElement("header");
header.addElement("etd:name").addText("test");
```

I've tried with **addElement(new QName("etd:name"))** but that shows me empty value **xmlns=""** which i dont want.

Comment: You might have to tell Dom4J what the namespace `etd` is, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191981/adding-namespace-and-namespace-prefix-using-dom4j

Comment: You mean: `Namespace etd = new Namespace("etd",""); new QName("name", etd)` ? That adds `xmlns:etd=""` :/

Comment: Something like that

Comment: Works but still i have **xmlns:etd=""**. How to remove this ?

Comment: When someone parses your XML, their parser may need to know where the `etd` elements are defined so it can tell that this is a valid document. Usually, the `xmlns` element will contain the location of the the XSD that you are referring to...

Comment: I've got xmlns argument in root section, I don't want anywhere more